# Are speed limits used for departure turns imposed also on the rest of the procedure?

Tags: departure-sid

*ICAO*'s PANS-OPS manual 8168 ("Aircraft Operations") defines turing departures as described below:

> **2.4 Turning Departures.** When a departure route requires a turn of more than 15°, it is called a turning departure.

It also defines maximum speeds used for turning departures.

> **2.4.4 Turn Speeds.** The maximum speeds used for departure turns shall be those of the final missed approach increased by
>   10 per cent to account for increased aeroplane mass in departure (see Table II-2-2-1), unless otherwise annotated on the
>   procedure.

[image]

What I am having trouble understanding is if these speed limits are valid only while the aircraft is performing the turn, and are cancelled during the subsequent straight track of the procedure (only for them to be valid again when another turn takes place).

I am asking because I remember reading somewhere that a speed limit imposed on a fix remains active for the rest of the procedure, unless it is cancelled by another speed restriction.

Thanks for anything that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The point of speed limits on fixes is spacing. The speed limits on turns above are to limit the turn radius. Those are two completely different reasons and there is no reason to think they are connected.

Comment: @StephenS Thanks for your input. However, doesn't this imply that the fix where the turn is initiated should have a speed limit less or equal to one of the above maximum speeds? If not, then theoretically the aircraft could perform a turn with a turn radius greater than the maximum allowed.